# React.js - Navbar is not defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I get this error in my navbar.jsx file.Navbar is defined in react-bootstrap.js. I add react-bootstrap.js to my bundles, but it still not working. How to solve that?

```
var MyNavbar = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (<Navbar>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav pullRight>
              <MenuItem eventKey={1}>...</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={2}>...</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={3}>...</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem eventKey={4}>...</MenuItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>);
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<MyNavbar/>,document.getElementById('navbar'));
```

Im trying to bundle my js and jsx files to _Layout.cshtml

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles/main").Include(
            "~/Scripts/react/react.js",
            "~/Scripts/react/react-dom.js",
            "~/Scripts/react/react-bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js",
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js",
            "~/Scripts/Components/Navbar.jsx"
        ));
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

Layout.csthml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="navbar"></div>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
```

[image]

Comment: Just created this [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/zawuforice/1/edit?html,js,output) with your React js code with an slight change to it in the first line, to get access to the `NavBar`, `MenuItem` and `Nav` Components from the global defined `ReactBootstrap` var. Have you checked in your devtools console if `ReactBootstrap` is defined?

Comment: Thank you, Im just forget to import components from ReactBootstrap. Just added this line `const { Navbar, Nav, MenuItem } = ReactBootstrap;` and now everything works.